# Not able to download all the images using request python

Tags: python, url, request, dataset, tqdm

I have 1k of image urls in a csv file and I am trying to download all the images from the urls. I don't know why I am not able to download all the images. Here is my code:

```
print('Beginning file download with requests')
path = '/home/tt/image_scrap/image2'
for idx, url in tqdm(enumerate(dataset['url']), total=len(dataset['url'])):
    response = requests.get(url,stream=True)
    time.sleep(2)

    filename = url.split("/")[-1]
    with open(path+'/'+filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: can you specify your problem? are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am not getting any error, just cant found the exact number of downloaded images based on the number of urls . thanks

Comment: The downloaded files are less than the expected value.

Comment: Well, you only use the last segment of the URL as the file name. There might be duplicates in that last segment (e.g. `foo/001.jpg` and `bar/001.jpg`) so some files get overwritten. Instead, you could replace each `/` with `_`, or create a directory hierarchy reflecting the path in the URI, or just append the `idx` to each file name.

Comment: Do not add new information in comments, use [edit] to add it to your question. Else you risk people missing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try / Except statements are really good for these type of 'errors':
Try this:

```
try:
    with open(path+'/'+filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
```